# how i can fix this . when in put * and when i put +

Tags: probability

we have this :
Traffic management has decided to change the license plate number of a car so that consists of seven boxes, the first three fields can contain 0 to three **characters** and the remaining four digits from 0 to four **digits** and we can't  allowed to board the existence of an empty car.
1 . How many different paintings that can be printed?
2 . Assuming that there are 100 vehicles from the letters of the word are not allowed to print their meanings unacceptable. What becomes possible number of paintings
Then print them?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you compute the number of plates possible with just two characters?  With three?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: 29390 it is the right number in question 1 @RossMillikan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that the standard upper-case  English alphabet is used for the character part. Temporarily assume that the empty plate is allowed.

Then the character part of the plate can be chosen in $1+26+26^2+26^3$ ways. For **every** such choices, the digits part can be filled in $1+10+10^2+10^3+10^4$ ways.

To compute the total number of possible plates, multiply, and subtract $1$ because the empty plate is not allowed.

If $100$ "words" are forbidden in the character part, none of them the empty word, make the obvious minor modification.

Comment: i just wondrerd about this : 1+26+262+263 . why we put the 1 number ?

Comment: Because in your description of possible plates, the problem allowed use to use $0$ alphabetic characters. So for example the plate that just says $262$ is legal.  The $1$ is for the $0$-length "word."

Comment: OK . you mean that we have the three characters so we have (26+ 26*26 + 26*26*26) and we put the 1 because we can't print empty plate why we repeated this 1 in numbers from 0 to 9 . can we put just number or characters without the others

Comment: this is what i have in 1 is this right ? @André Nicolas

Comment: Let us forget about the no empty plate temporarily. Then the number is $(1+26^1+26^2+26^3)(1+10^1+10^2+10^3+10^4)$. Subtract $1$ at the end because of the $1$ forbidden plate. Note that bare A is allowed ("empty" number part), also AX, also $234$.

Comment: OK . in the first question we put this . and what about 100 doesn't allow . how can we do that . please explain it in few words

Comment: i still wondered about why we put 1

Comment: OK, let's not put in a $1$. Then we get $X=(26+26^2+26^3)(10+10^2+10^3+10^4)$. But we have **not yet** counted the plates that are a word and no digits, like ME, or just digits like 247. (i) word, no digits: $Y=26+26^2+26^3$; (ii) just digits: $Z=10+10^2+10^3+10^4$. Total is $X+Y+Z$, which gives same result as in the answer I posted.

Comment: you are so great . thank you soo much

Comment: You are welcome. I am pleased that the last comment was helpful. The solution I had posted was perhaps a little too abstract.

Comment: ok thank you again . @http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%c3%a9-nicolas

Comment: what about if we have 100 words blocked in plate . how can we do that

Comment: That was mentioned briefly in the answer. If none of these blocked words is the "empty" word, we get $(1+26+26^2+26^3-100)(1+10+10^2+10^3+10^4)-1$.